# Can a photon be entangled with an electron?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-entanglement

In QFT is it possible to quantum entangle the polarization of a photon with the spin of an electron? How could this be done? Would it be possible, for example, to use the flipping of the electron spin in the hyperfine structure process?

Comment: hyperfine structure happens in  energy levels in bound states. Any entanglement would be with the atom as a whole, not the electron.which would still be bound

Comment: maybe this would be of interest https://www.physi.uni-heidelberg.de/Forschung/apix/APS/lectures/winter2012/2011_Tashenov.pdf